# jQuery click event delay when user stops clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

We have a html input with a increase and decrease button beside, to change the value into the input by clicking. Problem now is that the form directly submits after click.

We want to add a delay of 1 second, when the user stops clicking. We already tried the delay function, but we face the issue that this directly creates a delay of 1 second. So when the user is not ready clicking, after 1 second the form is still submitted.

We want to change that, so the form is only submitted after 1 second, after the user stops clicking.

How can we achieve that?

HTML:

```
        <div class="product-cart-qty-item" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>">
            <div class="product-cart-qty-block">
            <button type="button" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-dec"  class="decreaseQty"><i class="far fa-minus"></i></button>
                <input id="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
                name="cart[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
                data-cart-item-id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getSku() ?>"
                value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getQty() ?>"
                type="number"
                size="4"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>"
                class="input-text qty"
                data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}">                                             
            <button type="button" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-upt" class="increaseQty"><i class="far fa-plus"></i></button>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#<?php echo $_item->getId();?>-upt, #<?php echo $_item->getId();?>-dec').on("click",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var ctrl = ($(this).attr('id').replace('-upt','')).replace('-dec','');          
    var currentQty = $("#cart-"+ctrl+"-qty").val();
    if($this.hasClass('increaseQty')){
        var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)+parseInt(1);
         $("#cart-"+ctrl+"-qty").val(newAdd);
         $('form#form-validate').submit();
    }else{
         if(currentQty>1){
            var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)-parseInt(1);
            $("#cart-"+ctrl+"-qty").val(newAdd);
            $('form#form-validate').submit();
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: `delay` = "pause".   The term you're looking for is `debounce` - there's various solutions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to edit your code to make it work in an example because it has so much PHP mixed in it.  However, here's a simplified example with just a button you you click to increase a number and after a delay when stopped clicking it shows a message.  I think you can adapt this into your code.

Basically on click you need to start a timer, and save it.  On each click you also have to clear any previous timers and re-save the new timer to the same variable.

```js
var $input = $('#the-number');
var $btnDecrease = $('#decrease');
var $btnIncrease = $('#increase');

var timer = null;


$btnDecrease.on('click', function(){
  var num = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
  $input.val(num - 1);
  beginSubmitDelay();
});

$btnIncrease.on('click', function(){
  var num = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
  $input.val(num + 1);
  beginSubmitDelay();
});

function beginSubmitDelay(){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#message').show();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' readonly id='the-number' value='0'>
<button type='button' id='decrease'>-</button>
<button type='button' id='increase'>+</button>

<h4 id='message' style='color:green; display:none;'>Submitted!</h4>
```

Comment: This works better than a "standard" debounce - debounce is usually used to swallow/skip/ignore events except the last one, eg when scrolling or initiating a search when user has stopped typing.  In this case, OP needs those events.  (though it could be done with two events - one debounced and the other changing the value)

Answer (score 2):

Basic debounce function using a timeout and clear it when user does another action

```js
let submitTimer;
$(".yourSelector").on("click", function () {
  // cancel last submission
  if (submitTimer) window.clearTimeout(submitTimer);

  // your inc/dec logic

  // call submit after a delay
  submitTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('form#form-validate').submit();
  }, 1000);
});
```

To make it with a reusable debounce method

```js
const debounce => (func, timeout) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
};

const submitForm = debounce(() => $('form#form-validate').submit(), 1000);

$(".yourSelector").on("click", () => {
  // your inc/dec logic
  
  submitForm();
});
```